# Mytubeelement being injected in to page

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm making a page that visualizes some data using d3.js. At the moment, I only use d3.js and jquery but I have some very mysterious code that's being injected in the page when I inspect the page. The code is:

```
<mytubeelement id="myTubeRelayElementToPage" event="preferencesUpdated" data="{&quot;bundle&quot;:{&quot;label_delimitor&quot;:&quot;
 :&quot;,&quot;percentage&quot;:&quot;
 %&quot;,&quot;smart_buffer&quot;:&quot;
 Smart Buffer&quot;,&quot;start_playing_when_buffered&quot;:&quot;
 Start playing when buffered&quot;,&quot;sound&quot;:&quot;
 Sound&quot;,&quot;desktop_notification&quot;:&quot;
 Desktop Notification&quot;,&quot;continuation_on_next_line&quot;:&quot;
 -&quot;,&quot;loop&quot;:&quot;
 Loop&quot;,&quot;only_notify&quot;:&quot;
 Only Notify&quot;,&quot;estimated_time&quot;:&quot;
 Estimated Time&quot;,&quot;global_preferences&quot;:&quot;
 Global Preferences&quot;,&quot;no_notification_supported_on_your_browser&quot;:&quot;
 No notification style supported on your browser version&quot;,&quot;video_buffered&quot;:&quot;
 Video Buffered&quot;,&quot;buffered&quot;:&quot;
 Buffered&quot;,&quot;hyphen&quot;:&quot;
 -&quot;,&quot;buffered_message&quot;:&quot;
 The video has been buffered as requested and is ready to play.&quot;,&quot;not_supported&quot;:&quot;
 Not Supported&quot;,&quot;on&quot;:&quot;
 On&quot;,&quot;off&quot;:&quot;
 Off&quot;,&quot;click_to_enable_for_this_site&quot;:&quot;
 Click to enable for this site&quot;,&quot;desktop_notification_denied&quot;:&quot;
 You have denied permission for desktop notification for this site&quot;,&quot;notification_status_delimitor&quot;:&quot;
 ;&quot;,&quot;error&quot;:&quot;
 Error&quot;,&quot;adblock_interferance_message&quot;:&quot;
 Adblock (or similar extension) is known to interfere with SmartVideo. Please add this url to adblock whitelist.&quot;,&quot;calculating&quot;:&quot;
 Calculating&quot;,&quot;waiting&quot;:&quot;
 Waiting&quot;,&quot;will_start_buffering_when_initialized&quot;:&quot;
 Will start buffering when initialized&quot;,&quot;will_start_playing_when_initialized&quot;:&quot;
 Will start playing when initialized&quot;,&quot;completed&quot;:&quot;
 Completed&quot;,&quot;buffering_stalled&quot;:&quot;
 Buffering is stalled. Will stop.&quot;,&quot;stopped&quot;:&quot;
 Stopped&quot;,&quot;hr&quot;:&quot;
 Hr&quot;,&quot;min&quot;:&quot;
 Min&quot;,&quot;sec&quot;:&quot;
 Sec&quot;,&quot;any_moment&quot;:&quot;
 Any Moment&quot;,&quot;popup_donate_to&quot;:&quot;
 Donate to&quot;,&quot;extension_id&quot;:&quot;
 lnkdbjbjpnpjeciipoaflmpcddinpjjp&quot;},&quot;prefs&quot;:{&quot;desktopNotification&quot;:true,&quot;soundNotification&quot;:true,&quot;logLevel&quot;:0,&quot;allowPromotion&quot;:true,&quot;enable&quot;:true,&quot;loop&quot;:false,&quot;hidePopup&quot;:true,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false,&quot;autoBuffer&quot;:false,&quot;autoPlayOnBuffer&quot;:false,&quot;autoPlayOnBufferPercentage&quot;:42,&quot;autoPlayOnSmartBuffer&quot;:true,&quot;quality&quot;:&quot;
 default&quot;,&quot;fshd&quot;:false,&quot;onlyNotification&quot;:false,&quot;enableFullScreen&quot;:true,&quot;saveBandwidth&quot;:false,&quot;hideAnnotations&quot;:false,&quot;turnOffPagedBuffering&quot;:false}}"></mytubeelement>
```

I've added linebreaks for clarity, but in the code it's all on one line. Does anyone have any idea what this is? Searching for the element 'mytubeelement' doesn't tell me anything.

The code that I'm writing is just a simple page, drawing a bar graph using d3.

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,4500,9000,13500,18000])
    .range(["red","orange", "yellow","green","blue"]);

var width = 600,
    height = 500;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 70};

var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]).range([0,width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,18000])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis  = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class","y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

chart.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x",-200)
    .attr("y",-margin.left+15)
    .text("Steps")
    .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")

var barWidth = width / computedDataArray.length;


var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(computedDataArray)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, j) { return "translate(" + ((j-15)*barWidth) + ",0)"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
.attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.value);} );
```

Comment: And what's the code that's generating this?

Comment: I've no idea! That's what I'm trying to work out. I'm using WebStorm 9 as my IDE, but I don't think that's responsible.

Comment: What is the code that you're running?

Comment: Just drawing some simple d3 bar graphs. I've edited my post to add that code that I've written, but I've no idea why or how that would inject that odd HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extensions called "SmartVideo For YouTube™" it automatically adds that youtube element to your pages...

Answer (score 4):

Do you, by any chance, have some type of video buffering plugin installed?

I noticed the same thing (mytubelement being inserted into code) and I remembered that the plugin I had installed would inject code into webpages I visited.

If you have any video buffering plugin, would you try disabling the plugin and seeing whether that resolves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to plugin called SmartVideo For YouTube™. I disabled the plugin and the element insertion was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The **[SmartVideo for Youtube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smartvideo-for-youtube/lnkdbjbjpnpjeciipoaflmpcddinpjjp)** chrome extension does this.